# Update Product attribute value with custom option value on Add to cart in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.3

I have created three product attributes Length, Width, and Height. These will be used to calculate shipping for TNT Shipping Australia.

[image]

Now there will be custom options in some products as different dimensions. For this, I have created text fields in radio type custom options to save Length, Width, and Height as in the image.

[image]

Now in frontend on selecting the custom options, the Product attributes Length, Width and Height should be updated with the selected custom options Length, width and Height values. So TNT can calculate the shipping price with the selected values.

I was doing with Plugin using aroundAddProduct I am not getting how I will save the attributes values with the selected custom option values.

Or I have to go with the Observer .

Comment: Do you want to create a new variation of product every time when a user selects custom options? Because when you update the values of attributes on every add to cart, product variation will become different.

Comment: I have to use this custom options Length, width, and height options to treat as product attribute options as in the first image as TNT extension takes attributes values.

Comment: Any have idea I used Mageworx Product Options extension and need to get those custom option field in product rest API option's value ?